# Matlab Publish Image PDF

Tags: matlab, publish, simulink

I want to include a picture of my Simulink diagram when I publish my script. I currently print it to an image and manually add it in later.

I read on the [Matlab website](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/marking-up-matlab-comments-for-publishing.html#btj5juu-1) that I could do this by including a comment `<<FILENAME.jpg>>` and the publishing tool would pick it up and add it to my report. Unfortunately all this does is add a link to the image, which is not helpful when printing it out.

This is what I have:

```
print(['-s',simName], '-djpeg', ['html/',simName,'.jpg'])
% <<simName.jpg>>
```

I've also tried [these tips](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/294185) before, but they didn't work for me either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have tried should work. In fact it should work with any JPG file. have you tried what the example from the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/matlab_prog/marking-up-matlab-comments-for-publishing.html#btj5juu-1)?

> To produce an HTML file containing `surfpeaks.jpg` from a MATLAB file:
>
> 1. Create a subfolder called `html` in your current folder.
> 2. Create `surfpeaks.jpg` by running this code in the Command Window.

```
saveas(surf(peaks),'html/surfpeaks.jpg');
```

> 3. Publish this MATLAB code to HTML.

```
%% Image Example 
% This is a graphic: 
% 
% <<surfpeaks.jpg>> 
%
```

The alternative is to open the Simulink system with `open_system`. This will create a snapshot of the model in the published HTML provided the model is closed when the `open_system` command is issued.

```
%% Include snapshot of f14 model
%
open_system('f14')
%
```

If none of these work, then there's something fundamentally wrong with your MATLAB installation, of the way you are using the publish command.

Comment: For PDF, you probably don't want to put the images in the `html` subfolder, but in the same directory as your script.

Comment: Have you tried HTML? If it works with HTML, but not with PDF, then it'll give you a clue as to what is going wrong. You also need to give more details: script, where the files are located, how you publish it and what the output looks like, any error messages, etc...

Comment: This is what I got: [Image](http://i.imgur.com/drn6ijD.png)
With this code:
`%% Simulink
%<<HW6_1_sim.jpg>>
open_system('HW6_1_sim')
%`

The script ouputs a few plots using Simulink. The jpg is located now both in html and the same folder as the simulink and .m file.

I publish it by going to the top and clicking publish. I have it changed to pdf. I tried html too, but that didn't work either.

Comment: Where is the JPG file located relative to where your script is? How are you publishing your script? Which output format are you using? Have you tried different output formats? Did you make sure that the Simulink model is closed before publishing?

Comment: Ah it turns out the issue was closing the Simulink file. After that the open_system command worked for both html and pdf.

I also originally thought I was supposed to put that command in the publishing script window, not my actual code. 
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

open_system('filename.slx')

make sure the simulink program is in the same folder as the script.